# How To Perform PL/SQL Function Parameter Substitution on Sequence Name?

Tags: plsql

This is driving me crazy!

I am calling a PL/SQL Function, `GetNextVal`, passing in a variable ProgCode (like "SLC").
The function calls one of many matching, preexisting sequences, in this case `SLC_seq.NextVal`. On the next call another `ProgCode` is passed (say "KLY"), but the function returns the `nextval` of the first `ProgCode` sequence?
The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getNextVal(ProgCode IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS next_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT &ProgCode._seq.NextVal INTO next_val FROM DUAL;
RETURN(next_val); 
END;
/
```

A Quick Looping Test Script:

```
  declare
  type table_varchars is table of varchar2(4);
  var_table_varchar table_varchars;
  begin
  var_table_varchar := table_varchars('KLY','LGC','NLC','SLC');
  for e in 1..var_table_varchar.count loop
   for j in 1..10 loop
   dbms_output.put_line(var_table_varchar(e) || ': ' ||
   getnextval(var_table_varchar(e)));
  end loop;
 end loop;
 end;
/
```

Test Output:

```
KLY: 201
KLY: 202
KLY: 203
KLY: 204
KLY: 205
KLY: 206
KLY: 207
KLY: 208
KLY: 209
KLY: 210
LGC: 211
LGC: 212
LGC: 213
LGC: 214
LGC: 215
LGC: 216
LGC: 217
LGC: 218
LGC: 219
LGC: 220
NLC: 221
NLC: 222
NLC: 223
NLC: 224
NLC: 225
NLC: 226
NLC: 227
NLC: 228
NLC: 229
NLC: 230
SLC: 231
SLC: 232
SLC: 233
SLC: 234
SLC: 235
SLC: 236
SLC: 237
SLC: 238
SLC: 239
SLC: 240
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to unset `&ProgCode` in the function?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > First, you cannot use substituion variable (`&`) in a PL/SQL since it is an exclusive feature of SQL*Plus. Hence, you must use binding variable instead, `:`
- > Secondly, you dont have to set a value inside a function or a procedure, that is the reason why you are getting the next value of the first sequence since when you complie the function you set the ProgCode to be 'KLY'. You have to use the parameter as it is inside the block.
- > Try this :

> ```
>    create or replace FUNCTION getNextVal(ProgCode IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
>
>    IS 
>    next_val VARCHAR2(200);
>    v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);
>    BEGIN
>
>    v_sql := 'SELECT '||ProgCode||'_seq.nextval FROM DUAL';
>    --dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
>     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO NEXT_VAL;
>
>    RETURN NEXT_VAL;
>    END;
> ```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly! Thx @brenners1302